# << and >> symbols in Erlang

Tags: erlang

First of all, I'm an Erlang rookie here.  I need to interface with a MySQL database and I found the [erlang-mysql-driver](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-mysql-driver/source/checkout).  I'm trying that out, and am a little confused by some of the syntax.

I can get a row of data from the database with this (greatly oversimplified for brevity here):

```
Result = mysql:fetch(P1, ["SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE column2='", Key, "'"]),  
case Result of  
    {data, Data} ->  
        case mysql:get_result_rows(Data) of  
            [] -> not_found;  
            Res ->  
              %% Now 'Res' has the row
```

So now here is an example of what `Res' has:

```
[[<<"value from column1">>, <<"value from column2">>]]
```

I get that it's a list of records.  In this case, the query returned 1 row of 2 columns.

**My question is:**
What do the `<<` and `>>` symbols mean?  And what is the best (Erlang-recommended) syntax for turning a list like this into a records which I have defined like:

```
-record(  
    my_record,  
    {   
      column1 = ""  
      ,column2 = ""  
    }  
 ).
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just a small note: the results are not bit string **comprehensions** per see, they are just **bit strings**. However you can use bit string comprehensions to produce a sequence of bit strings (which is described above with the generators and that), much like lists and lists comprehensions.

you can use erlang:binary_to_list/1 and erlang:list_to_binary/1 to convert between binary and strings (lists).

The reason the mysql driver returns bit strings is *probably* because they are much faster to manipulate.

Comment: i found bitstring_to_list was working.  i'll have to look up binary_to_list also.  i did manage to get my code working, but i'm always looking to make it more correct.

Answer (score 6):

In your specific example, you can do the conversion by matching on the returned column values, and then creating a new record like this:

```
case mysql:get_result_rows(Data) of
  [] ->
    not_found;  
  [[Col1, Col2]] ->  
    #my_record{column1 = Col1, column2 = Col2}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

These are **bit string comprehensions.**

Bit string comprehensions are analogous to List Comprehensions. They are used to generate bit strings efficiently and succinctly.

Bit string comprehensions are written with the following syntax:

```
<< BitString || Qualifier1,...,QualifierN >>
```

BitString is a bit string expression, and each Qualifier is either a generator, a bit string generator or a filter.

• A generator is written as:

```
 Pattern <- ListExpr.
```

ListExpr must be an expression which evaluates to a list of terms.

• A bit string generator is written as:

```
 BitstringPattern <= BitStringExpr.
```

`BitStringExpr` must be an expression which evaluates to a bitstring.

• A filter is an expression which evaluates to true or false. 
The variables in the generator patterns shadow variables in the function clause surrounding the bit string comprehensions.

A bit string comprehension returns a bit string, which is created by concatenating the results of evaluating `BitString` for each combination of bit string generator elements for which all filters are true.

Example:

```
1> << << (X*2) >> || 
<<X>> <= << 1,2,3 >> >>.
<<2,4,6>>
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the reply.  I'm going to try to write a MySQL Row -> Record function now and see what happens...

Comment: And in my case, I don't have any filters or generators, so it looks like I can simply call erlang:bitstring_to_list/1.  Thanks very much!

Comment: The most important meaning of the << and >> is to denote binaries itself. There is no sign of bit string comprehension in the question!